# Writing test case for Loading Cache guava

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, unit-testing, guava

I am trying to test the asynchronous loading of cache over my database. I am using Google guava loading cache, which in turn uses Cache loader refreshing the given key asynchronously (as explained in https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)

I was trying the following steps to test

- The refresh duration : 1sec
- Make a call to cache, key is absent. Call to the mock DB is made
- Thread.sleep(2000L)
- Make another call for same key. Since the key is present and refresh period is over, the stale value should be returned and async refresh should be kicked off
- Thread.sleep(2000L)
- Make another call for the same key.

Since I am mocking the dao, I expect it to be called atleast twice. However, when I am trying to verify the mock, it fails saying that mock was just called once. How do I ensure the dao is called twice? I am mocking the Thread Factory, while creating Executor which is being called for creating a new thread, as expected. Why is the second call to dao never made? Am I missing anything here? I am using new FixedThread Pool executor and decorating it as listening decorator.

What is the right way to test such refreshing caches? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: New wiki location: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
CacheBuilder.ticker(youtTicker)
```

and pass a `FakeTicker` to advance the time at will.

Unless you *really* want to test the multithreaded behavior, forget threads and test it synchronously.

Look at the source code of e.g., [CacheRefreshTest](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-tests/test/com/google/common/cache/CacheRefreshTest.java?r=852dcdc3a06a889d9a24e8e02d25d4cd1aa5bf37).

Maybe you can spot the problem by simplifying your test... that's all I can say without your exact code.

Comment: Thanks for your response maaartinus. As per the documentation of CacheBuilder, ticker is useful when testing caches configured with expireAfter*. However, my cache is configured with refreshAfterWrite, not sure if Ticker would be useful. Shall try it out anyways.

Comment: @u07103 I'd bet any amount that the ticker is the only time source used in a given cache. Anything else would be foolish. I guess, the docs mentions "expire" only as "refresh" is a newer feature.

Comment: @u07103 [Issue 1836](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1836) created.